# Memory error when trying to read a 90 MB EPUB file

Tags: android, epub

I was trying to read epub file stored in sdcard using epub library.
The epub file size was 90 MB. When I run this application it gives an error "out of memory".

Does anybody have an idea/suggestion/solution how to solve this?

Comment: Its so complicated case in android to read 90Mb file,,,,But may its work with buffer...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to open up the file in an archive manager like 7-zip, and take a look at the individual file sizes. Some e-book readers (like Sony's) have size limits on the individual .xhtml files in the .epub archive - we've been splitting ours out into about 100KB uncompressed each.

If you do find that the xhtml files inside the .epub archive are too large, you can use a tool like Calibre to split the file into smaller bits.